# How can I tell if my multiple network interfaces are working ok?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, routing, ubuntu-14.04

On Ubuntu 14.04 x86-64 I have a wireless broadband connection and a USB tethered one (it's on 4G, not the same wireless):

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan1
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 usb0
```

I have then the following also:

```
ifconfig

...

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:36:2c:04:05:7c  
          inet addr:192.168.42.248  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::36:2cff:fe04:57c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3367 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:1
          TX packets:3669 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2434689 (2.4 MB)  TX bytes:637911 (637.9 KB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:cc:20:75:e1:8d  
          inet addr:192.168.0.4  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::16cc:20ff:fe75:e18d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3806 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2283536 (2.2 MB)  TX bytes:583794 (583.7 KB)
```

It all looks like it's supposed to be working as intended (i.e. both network connections are up, my machine got 2 IPs, ...).
Then I wanted to use the [bind](http://www.ryde.net/code/bind.c.txt) *shim* to force processes on one connection (or another) and those only work when I specify the IP of the *default* connection/gateway.
The following works (please note this is on the tethered USB - 4G):

```
BIND_ADDR="192.168.42.248" LD_PRELOAD=./bind.so chromium-browser
```

And this doesn't (my broadband):

```
BIND_ADDR="192.168.0.4" LD_PRELOAD=./bind.so chromium-browser
```

Of course, when I unplug the USB phone, *wlan0* magically starts working again...

What am I doing wrong? Any idea?

Comment: From the looks of it, your .0.0 route doesn't work when you're bound to the 42.0 network because your default route points to a gateway at 42.129, which you can't access on the other network. You need a route for 0.0.0.0/0 on 192.168.0.0/24, probably whatever your router is.

Comment: @Xyon How can I verify that? Even if I use the *bind* shim? That LD_PRELOAD trick is supposed to force all binds and connect to 192.168.0.4?

Comment: Well it not pulling external sites suggests that it *is* working, because otherwise you'd get connectivity through the other link. Your broadband network isn't completely set up, I don't know how bind is supposed to handle that situation but the kernel doesn't know where to send your packets.

Comment: @Xyon I guess I'll have to write a simple test executable to see what errors the kernel is returning when creating TCP/UDP connections?

Comment: No, I wouldn't go that far. What you're trying to do needs a second route table, bound to your other interface, so the system understands how to handle requests from each interface. See https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System for a good resource on the concept.

Comment: Pls read my answer.

Comment: You both are right, in fact if I use *BIND_ADDR="192.168.0.4" LD_PRELOAD=./bind.so firefox*, I can open the broadband router just fine (on 192.168.0.1).

Comment: @MariusMatutiae would this do it in one line: `ip route add from 192.168.0.0/24 gw 192.168.0.1 dev wlan1` or maybe `ip route add from 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.0.1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your bind does not work has nothing to with bind, a trick I use too, and everything to do with the fact that you have only one default gateway, on the `usb0` NIC, while you should have one on either NIC, otherwise connection to WAN sites from `wlan0` will not be routed.

Linux allows the existence of multiple gateways (one per interface, virtual or not), under the regimen of `policy-based routing`. What you need to do is  to have two separate routing tables, one for `usb0` and one for `wlan0`, and a rule telling the kernel which one to use; then `binding` an application to either interface will allow you to reach WAN sites.

You handle two routing tables as follows:  First, create two tables (Replace  and  with sensible names, same with IP1, DEV1, and so on):

```
echo 200 <NAME1> >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
echo 201 <NAME2> >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Add a gateway to each routing table (if needed):

```
ip route add <NET1> dev <DEV1> src <SRC1> table <NAME1>
ip route add <NET2> dev <DEV2> src <SRC2> table <NAME2>
```

Then a default route:

```
ip route add default via <IP1> table <NAME1>
ip route add default via <IP2> table <NAME2>
```

Then the rules to select the route table based on the source address:

```
ip rule add from <IP1> table <NAME1>
ip rule add from <IP2> table <NAME2>
```

Now you can bind application to either interface.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the answer I was looking for. Do you know if there's a way to do it programmatically? Are the changes persistent?

Comment: @Emanuele No, these changes are not persistent. The easiest thing is to put all of the above in an executable file, call it `my_config`, then, in `/etc/network/interfaces`, use `auto usb0; interface usb0 inet dhcp; post-up /path/to/my_config`, and raise interfaces with `ifup/ifdown usb0/wlan0`.

Comment: Actually my next question would have been what is the one liner command I can use to setup a temporary default gateway for a given IP address. Again, I don't want a static configuration, more than happy to input the one liner command each time. Thanks!

Comment: @Emanuele Put the above commands into an executable file, you have your one liner; to go back to the previous situation, bring don the two interfaces, then back up, and erase the two lines in the `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` file.

Comment: Would `ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan1` (or `ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev 192.168.0.1` do the trick of temporarily route all the packets for this subnet through that gateway?