# How to temporarily change the gateway of a secondary IP?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, routing

I have the following  situation:

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan1
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 usb0
```

And I would want to use a *one-liner* to setup the gateway of `192.168.0.0/24` to be `192.168.0.1` (current secondary ip is `192.168.0.4`).
Can I use something like

```
sudo ip route add from 192.168.0.4 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

?
Again, I need something temporary which forces all packets sent from `192.168.0.4` to pass from gateway `192.168.0.1` (don't want to setup a set of scripts/whatnot to do this). Is there a one liner I can use?

Cheers!

Comment: That can be made with asymmetric routing, but not as a one-liner as far as I know. More info on this: http://www.microhowto.info/howto/ensure_symmetric_routing_on_a_server_with_multiple_default_gateways.html

Comment: No, you cannot: re-read my answer here, http://superuser.com/questions/1018196/how-can-i-tell-if-my-multiple-network-interfaces-are-working-ok

Comment: What do you mean by "sent from 192.168.0.4"? Do you mean having a source IP address of exactly 192.168.0.4?

Comment: Gateways are per route, and Routes are per destination (Not Source) so you cannot set a gateway for a secondary IP; you can only set the gateway on the 192.168.0.0/24 to 192.168.0.1. In that case all traffic destined for the 192.168.0.0 net will go through 192.168.0.1, but it will do so regardless of whether the traffic is sourced from 192.168.0.4 or another ip on that LAN.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I'll try the below first answer; I hope you're wrong, but you _migth_ be just right :)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes

Comment: If you want to select routes based on more than the destination address, that’s called Policy Routing. I don’t have any experience with it, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to force all of your traffic thru `wlan1` instead instead of `usb0` is to force a new gateway: as sudo,

```
ip route del default
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan1
```

(I assume your gateway has IP address `192.168.0.1`, if not change accordingly). You can restore the previous situation by means of

```
ip route del default 
ip route add default via 192.168.42.129 dev usb0
```

If you do not know/remember the IP address of the gateway, then use instead

```
ip route del default
dhclient -v usb0
```

(`-v` option is for verbose, it does not exist on all distros, you *may* have to drop it).

You may also decide that you would like to have **two** gateways, one per interface; with the Linux kernel (and only with the Linux kernel) this can be done, you find [in David'Schwartz's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22770/two-interfaces-two-addresses-two-gateways) an excellent short explanation of how to do it. Once you do, you will have to decide thru which interface the output of each application passes (you **can** decide on a per-application basis). This means that a given application, say `ssh` may *bind* to either interface, or, in other words, that the IP address from which `ssh` starts can be either that of `usb0` or that of `wlan1`; the `rule` discussed by David Schwartz then takes care automatically of routing correctly `ssh`.

Notice that this way, you may have one `ssh` connection go thru `wlan1`, and another one going thru `wlan1`.